# Just Installed Ubuntu. cant enter passphrase

Tags: keyboard

I have recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. After I installed and replaced windows 7 it told me to restart. once I restarted, I came to a loading screen which says:

```
Unlocking the disk /dev/disk/by-uuid/33ebfb20-d2c-4738-80d3-0d34576dec03 (sda_crypt)
Enter passphrase:
```

after which there is a box.
the problem is neither the keyboard nor the mouse works.
So how do I enter the passphrase without keyboard, or how do I get the keyboard working?

I was able to solve this by connecting the keyboard to the usb3 output.

Comment: I should probably add that both keyboard and mouse worked during the installation process.

Comment: Click edit if you have more information.

Comment: Your keyboard working in bios?

Comment: Wireless keyboard?

Comment: it's a wired keyboard and it works in the bios

Answer (score 3):

The original poster reported in an edit that the problem was solved "by connecting the keyboard to the usb3 output."

That was it, I plugged the keyboard into a USB3 card and it started working. Keyboard worked fine in bios and during installation from an onboard USB2.